How do i reset the variable in setInterval js
I am having problem in which I want to logout user if there is no activity within 180 seconds if there is any then it will reset the timer but the problem is the timer is not resetting I checked through logs here my code.
if ($isManager || $isAdmin) {  ?>
    var total_session_time = 180; // In seconds. After this interval of time if user is ideal then clock timer will start in seconds
    //var total_session_time = 50000;//180; // In seconds. After this interval of time if user is ideal then clock timer will start in seconds
    var clock_time_start = total_session_time + 1;
    var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // alert('hello');
        // console.log('total_session_time->' + total_session_time)
        //idleTime = $('#idleTime').val();
        var sms_access_page = $('#sms_page_access').val(); // get val. for handle the logic of sms page will not logout.
        // console.log('sms_accss_if_value - '+sms_access_page);
        var idleInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if ($('#idleTime').val()) {
                idleTime = $('#idleTime').val();
            } else {
                idleTime = 0;
            }
            if ($('#pauseLogoutScript').val() == 0) {
                idleTime = parseInt(idleTime) + 5; // as interval is of 5 seconds added 5.
            }
            //console.log('idleTime ->'+idleTime);
            $('#idleTime').val(idleTime);
            if (idleTime > total_session_time) {
                count = clock_time_start - idleTime;
                // console.log('count ->' + count);
                if (count <= 0) {
                    if (sms_access_page != '' && sms_access_page == '7') {
                        console.log('sms page will not logout- ' + sms_access_page);
                    } else {
                        console.log('logging out');
                        window.location = 'index.php?r=site/logout'
                        //return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 5000); // 1000 = 1 sec
        $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
            $('#idleTime').val('');
        });
        $(this).keypress(function(e) {
            $('#idleTime').val('');
        });
    });
<?php }          ?>

Thank You in advance!
I want to reset the idleTime variable

You do several things in your timer: Advance or reset the idle time, compute the time passed, and log out the user. No wonder you get confused. This code should be simplified a lot. Simply record the last time an activity took place with something like performance.now(), which returns a time stamp. Then use the timer to check how long ago that was. If it was too long ago log the user out. There's no good reason to also track idle time in any way.

Here's a simplified version of your JavaScript:
var maxIdleTime     = 180000; // in milliseconds
var lastInteraction = performance.now();

$(function() {
    $(this).on("mousemove keydown"), function() {
        lastInteraction = performance.now();
    });

    setInterval(function() {        
        if (performance.now() > lastInteraction + maxIdleTime) {
            window.location = 'index.php?r=site/logout';
        }
    }, 5000); 
});

I left out the PHP and the SMS page stuff. The point is that this doesn't have to be very complicated.

Problem is last interaction is not updating when I do some activity hence causing the logout. My main concern is that I am getting logged out even tho I am doing the activities.

@DioBrando You have to be a bit more flexible. The code that you wrote isn't doing its job, it's bad code. It needs replacing. I suggested some new code for you to try. Try it. Please.
